# Check to see if array contains selected value and remove it if so

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a function that involves a checkbox functionality and I want it to check to see if the value selected is already in the array, and if so remove it.  This would be the case when someone "unchecks" the checkbox.

```
checkedCodes: any = [];

searchResultsCheckBox = (e) => {
    var row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    var charge = row.getElementsByClassName('chargeList')[0] as HTMLElement;
    var description = row.getElementsByClassName('descriptionList')[0] as HTMLElement;
    this.selectedCode = charge.innerText + " (" + description.innerText + ")";
    if (this.checkedCodes.includes(this.selectedCode)){
      // What should I put here? 
    }
    else {
      this.checkedCodes.push(this.selectedCode);
    }
}
```

I want something in the `if` statement to check to see if the `selectedCode` is already in the array `checkedCodes` and if so remove it.  Any suggestions will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know how to remove an item from an array?  use `array.splice()`

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Pass in the index you want to begin removing at, and then the number of items you want to remove.

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
console.log(arr);

var pos = arr.indexOf('three');
arr.splice(pos, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

### Edit

And just to be clear, here's how you'd modify your code do so this

```
if (this.checkedCodes.includes(this.selectedCode)){
  var pos = this.checkedCodes.indexOf(this.selectedCode)
  this.checkCodes.splice(pos, 1);
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for.  Your answer would indicate that I would know the position within the array, which I wouldn't.  I'm interested in removing the value that matches the incoming one

Comment: You're saying you want to remove an item from the array, but you have no idea which item it is or how to locate it?  Your code has `if (this.checkedCodes.includes(this.selectedCode)){` which suggests that you just found exactly what you want in the array.  So now you just need to get the index by doing `this.checkedCodes.indexOf(this.SelectedCode)`

Comment: that worked, THANK YOU!